# Allowing backslash through regular expression at the end of url

Tags: c#

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((nntp|sftp|ftp(s)?|http(s)?|gopher|news|file|telnet):\/\/)?(([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]*([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z]{1,6})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))(:\d+)?(\/[^:][^\s]*)?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid domainname.")]
```

It is my specific regular expression  in c sharp. It works fine on all my case but i need not to validate backslash at the end of url.

www.test.com/ should not give errormessage of invalid domain name.please help me.

Comment: Is there nothing in the [Uri class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) that will do what you are trying to do? what is your regex trying to match/avoid?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
^((nntp|sftp|ftps?|https?|gopher|news|file|telnet):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

add your protocols near ftp or http with separated by pipe(|)